# The word "game" in tags is redundant.

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed a few tags of the form "game-design" and "game-engine". Well, yeah. It's about games. We're on the Gamedev beta.

I've gone and stripped out "game" from all of these, just to get it done with, but if anyone's got a reason to put them back, now is the chance.

Edit: Similarly, the tag "game" should just be removed whenever it shows up. If it's not about games, it's on the wrong site.

Comment: I agree, this is the right thing to do.

Comment: I saw a few more pop up so I took care of those as well

Comment: One concern I have is findability through search engines as well as expectability. I fear some people may come here searching for "game design" in the search box and end up being presented an inaccurate set of results.

Comment: It's possible that could be a problem, but if we don't get enough search engine karma via links, we're doing something wrong. I feel like it will only be a problem if it's nowhere near the biggest problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you made the right decision, as long as the stripped version is still clear and unambiguous. There may the occasional exception.

The WebApp folks came to the same decision and it seems to have worked out well for them.

Answer (score 4):

The tag synonym feature should be used in this case I think example game-engine is synonymed to engine

Answer (score 0):

Game-engine, sure.

Game-design, however, I think should stay. If you say "design", you could mean code design, ie analysis, design, & architecture. "Game design" excludes code-design, and as I've seen it in the game design community, is the phrase of choice.

Comment: As a fun fact, in Japan, "design" in the context of game development commonly refers to the -graphical- design of the game (art). Game designers are called "planners".