# Should the "design" tag encompass architecture AND game design questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm a game designer and my main area of expertise is that, game design. While i find the technical aspects of a game *program* interesting, I expected finding game design related questions when selecting the "design" tag.

Shouldn't the technical and "end user" aspects of designing a game be under their own separate tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`design` as a tag isn't descriptive enough.  Just look at the questions with that tag: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design

I propose we break it up into 2 (or maybe 3) tags.

- `game-design` Yes I know it violates the ["games in tags is redundant"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/the-word-game-in-tags-is-redundant) rule, but I think in this case it's worth adding for clarity since it obviously isn't unambiguous enough.
- `level-design`
- `engine-design` (maybe as a synonym of `architecture`)

Comment: I'd agree that design is used inappropriately in most of those questions, but I don't think that's an argument for new tags, I think it's an argument for the descriptions of the tags to be clearer, and for the mods to guide the re-tagging.

Design, covering both game-design and level-design, and Architecture, covering software-design.

Comment: Well what I would like to do is simply rename `design` to `game-design`, and start retagging "engine design" questions as `architecture`.  `level-design` as a tag was just an afterthought.  Other than that tag I'm not suggesting any new tags.

Comment: I like the specificity created by having game-design and level-design as separate tags. People are always going to be tempted to just use the Design tag, so like @MrCranky said I think it's really going to be up to people capable of retagging to go through those questions and tag appropriately (if not done by then, I'll do it when I get home). As far as synonyms/merges for architecture/engine-design and what else I am not that deeply involved on that side to make any real judgement about it.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that there already *is* an [Architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) tag, so I would say yes, design is different from architecture. :)

Comment: In that case should all non-game design posts under "design" be moved to architecture? Or should a more specific tag be added? I'm noticing that the word "design" can also interpreted sometimes as graphical design. A more specific tag might be welcome.