# Need for software-design tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There was a question on Game Development where the tag didn't really fit the bill, but a "suitable" tag doesn't really exist.

[Software Design/Modelling method and tool for games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13482/software-design-modelling-method-and-tool-for-games)

The question is about software design methods, but is tagged game-design, which is wrong, but software-design doesn't exist, and architecture doesn't really fit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed this a bit here: [Should the "design" tag encompass architecture AND game design questions?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/should-the-design-tag-encompass-architecture-and-game-design-questions)

Personally I'm of the opinion that "architecture" *does* fit.

Comment: Sorry for the re-ask then. I'm not a game designer but I have notions and agree that the misuse of 'game-design' as a tag is repugnant :). In the case where the architecture tag is in debate, should we change tags or just leave the inappropriate tag?

Comment: If you see cleanup work that needs to be done, feel free to do it.  We all chip in to make the site a better place.

Comment: Got there before me :P

Answer (score 0):

I think it would fit pretty well in the `programming` tag, as well as the `tools` tag. I personally do not think it fits in `architecture` since it's more of a tool than the actual code itself.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. I would'nt say programming though, because he's not specifically asking for code, and for me tools would be more an actual program, though indeed he is asking for a 'tool' to help define an architecture.

Comment: @3nixios I would consider it to definitely be programming - it is part of the programming process. And UML is often done via UML modelling programs.

Comment: For me the design (which can be done on paper) and the actual programming of it are different. You can have a software design that requires certain things, but will not stipulate how it will be implemented, that is the programming side of things. Of course certain things are implicit with UML for example, but whether you implement it in C# or C++ is a programming problem. Anyway this is more a discussion for the forums methinks? :P