# Is Game-Design tag being misused or was there something that auto applied it?

Tags: discussion, tags

Being a game designer, I've been looking in the `game-design` tag to see if there are any questions I can help with.  Most of them seem to have nothing to do with the `game-design` tag.

> Game Design is the creation and balancing of game systems and mechanics. Not for programming questions about "design" of features, engines, etc.

[Should the "design" tag encompass architecture AND game design questions?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/103/11204)

So that question looks to be the inspiration for creating the `game-design` tag. I've gone through several questions and edited the tags, trying to add appropriate ones as I can.  But I was curious if there was a mass change as suggested in the meta question, or if it's just really being misused that much?

I'm happy to continue editing tags and looking for true game design questions in the tag list. Just wanted to check in here before sending a large list of tag edits for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly being mis-applied, which is somewhat understandable given it's extremely broad nature.

There have been no bulk tag edit operations (these are fairly obvious when they occur, as they tend to flood the active questions page with old questions "last modified by" the user who made the edit), merges, or automatic processes applied to the `game-design` tag that I'm aware of. It's just badly managed.

Comment: Alright, well then I'll continue making tag edits when they seem appropriate. Issue is I will most likely be filtering out, rather than filtering in. But hopefully keeping just examples of good questions for the tag, will lead to more quality questions being posted.