# The tag 'game' is still around

Tags: discussion, tags

Not much of a question here.  More of a pleasant reminder that tags should actually say something about the question.  I saw this [game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) on the front page today, and it has far too many instances on the site.

[The word "game" in tags is redundant.](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/the-word-game-in-tags-is-redundant)

I'm going to try to clear out some of these.  Feel free to assist.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the last few this morning. I also added the tag to the [list of bad tags](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted).